# How do I check whether an input string has alphabets in another string in Python?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, match

As the title says, how do I check whether an input string has alphabets in another string in Python?

The string specifies that only alphabets A to G ('ABCDEFG') can be used in the input string. However, my attempt did not get the results I want. Instead, input strings with alphabets in order such as 'ABC' and 'ABCD' work, while those not in order such as 'BADD' and 'EFEG' do not.

Please refer to my attempt below.

```
ID = 'ABCDEFG'
addcode=input('Enter new product code: ')
Code = []

if addcode in ID:
    Code.append(addcode)
    print(Code)
else:
    print("Product code is invalid")
```

Ideally, as long as the input string contain letters from A to G, it should be appended to 'Code' regardless of the order. How do I modify my code so that I can get the results I want? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx:

```
re.search('[a-zA-Z]', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting your input string (addcode) to a set and then see if it is a subset of ID. I am not converting ID into a set as it contains unique elements as per your code:

```
ID = 'ABCDEFG'
addcode = input('Enter new product code: ')
Code = []

if set(addcode).issubset(ID):
    Code.append(addcode)
    print(Code)
else:
    print("Product code is invalid")
```

If you want to use a RegEx based approach, you can do this:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("^[A-G]+$")
addcode = input('Enter new product code: ')
Code = []

if pattern.findall(addcode):
    Code.append(addcode)
    print(Code)
else:
    print("Product code is invalid")
```

We are checking if the input string contains only characters between **A-G** here i.e A,B,C,D,E,F,G. If there is a match, we append the input string and print it.

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable. You should check whether each letter of product code is present in the ID.

To achieve this you can use ID as tuple instead of single string.

```
ID = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')

addcode=input('Enter new product code: ')
Code = []
for l in range(0,len(addcode)):
    if addcode[l] in ID:
        Code.append(addcode[l])

    else:
        print("Product code is invalid")

print(Code)
```